# Flutter Plugin manifestPlaceholders error

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-plugin

I'm trying to create a plugin for flutter. My problem is that looks like flutter is not recognizing manifestPlaceholders for some reason (probably me doing something wrong).

So I added this lines to my `android/build.gradle` file.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        manifestPlaceholders = [auth0Domain: "example.auth0.com", auth0Scheme: "demo"] // this one for the manifestPlaceholders replacement.
    }
    ...
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.auth0.android:auth0:1.+' // this line to install auth0 dependency
}
```

But when I try to compile the app I get the following errors:

```sh
Attribute data@host at AndroidManifest.xml requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <auth0Domain> is provided.

Attribute data@scheme at AndroidManifest.xml requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <auth0Scheme> is provided.
```

I really don't know what I'm missing here. Your help will be much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Try adding it to `example/android/app/build.gradle` instead.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Since comments can be erased, I've added an answer for posterity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The placeholder needs to be added to the *app*'s `build.grade`. In a plugin, that means the example app's - `plugin_project/example/android/app/build.grade`.

That also means that you should add something to your plugin's readme. Users of your plugin will need to add it to their app project's `build.grade`. In an app project, that's `app_project/android/app/build.grade`.